# How to install OmniXml for Delphi Xe2/ OExport XLSX/ODS native Delphi/Lazarus import/export library

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, omnixml

I know this might be a simple question but i searched the internet and couldn't find an answer. I am trying to install OExport - XLSX/ODS native Delphi/Lazarus import/export library http://www.kluug.at/xlsx-ods-delphi.php , but in order to install it I need to have prior installed OmniXMl. So I have downloaded from here http://www.kluug.at/xlsx-ods-delphi.php as well. I have extracted the archive and I opened from the dpk folder the OmniXml_Dxe2 package. And in the Delphi IDE i know that i need to right click on the project name (respectively OmniXml_Dxe2.bpl ) and then click install; but install option is missing (attached a picture); Then I thought that i need to run the project instead. So I when I run the project an error appears ***"Cannot run project unless a host application is defined. Use the Run|Parameters..dialog..box"***

Could somebody please tell me where I am doing something wrong and what should I do in order to install OmniXml

[image: error image 1 click to enlarge]
[image: error image 2 click to enlarge]

Comment: have you installed all the dependencies?

Comment: @RBA, Hy, What depedencies are needed to install OmniXml because I didn't found anything about this? OmniXml is a dependecie for **OExport - XLSX/ODS native Delphi/Lazarus import/export library** but it don't know how to install OmniXML first as i mentioned above.

Comment: I haven't used OmniXML, so what I suggest you to do is: build the package for xe2 and add the dcu path to the IDE, and after that install OExport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because you are making a DLL or package, and they cannot be run. They only run when a host application is loading them, and you can use the Run/Parameters dialog to set this. But I suggest that you are really looking for the "Install" option for the project to load it as a package into Delphi.

Comment: I have done some research and what you wrote is correct. The situation changed a little bit. I will explain: When I load the OExport-XL package in the IDE and compile I have the error about OmniXml-Dxe2.dcu missing; i found that on the zip file downloaded with OmniXML and add it to my project. Then I have 0 errors, but when I right click and search the install option for the O Export package I can't find it.

Comment: I have solved the issue by talking to the author of the component-Neither OmniXML nor OExport are design-time components that have to be installed in the Delphi IDE - they are pure classes. Just add the path of the directories with .pas units to your Library path and compile the XE2 packages.